# How do I formulate the condition to have make two different responses, one for the removed and one for the non removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user selects to delete a department or location, then the system checks against the database to see if that entry is used in other tables (ie personnel assigned to that department) and, if so, should prevent removal.

If it prevents removal I want to have a popup saying: "This department/location can't be removed."

At the moment it is only showing: "Removed" for both elements, the removed ones and the ones that are not being deleted.

How can I make the if condition for the two different responses, one for the removed and one for the non removed?

What I have tried:

```
function toggleConfirmDep(message, func) {
    
    if (!event) var event = window.event;
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();


    employeeID = $(event.target).closest(".buttons").siblings("form").find("#id").text();

    if ($('#confirmDep').css('display') == "none") {

        $('#confirmDep').show()
        $('#depQuestion').show()
        $('#depResponse').hide()

        let addOrRemove = capitalizeFirstLetter(message.split(" ")[0])
        addOrRemove == "Add" ? addOrRemove += "ed" : addOrRemove += "d"

        $('#depMessage').text(message)
        $('#depButton').attr('onClick', `
        
            ${func.toString()};
            $('#depQuestion').hide()
            $('#depResponse').show()

            if (event.cancelBubble == true) {

                $('#depResponseMessage').text('${addOrRemove}');

            } else if (event.cancelBubble == false) {

                $('#depResponseMessage').text('This department can't be removed.');

            } else {

                $('#depResponseMessage').text('${addOrRemove}');

            }



            
            setTimeout(function(){
            
                $('#confirmDep').hide();
                
                $('#profilePage').hide();
                
                window. location. reload(1);
                
            }, 1500);
            
        `)

    } else {
        
        $('#confirmDep').css('display', 'none')

    }

}

function removeDepartment() {

    let departmentName = $('#removeDepartmentDepartment').val()

    $.getJSON(`php/getAllDepartments.php`, function (departments) {

        let departmentID = departments.data.filter(dep => dep.name == departmentName)[0].id

        $.ajax({

            data: {
                'id': departmentID
            },
            url: 'php/deleteDepartmentByID.php', 
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data) {

                $('#removeDepartmentDepartment').find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
    
            }

        })

    }); 

}

function toggleRemoveDepartment() {
    
    if ($('#removeDepartmentOverlay').css('display') == "none") {
    
        $('#removeDepartmentOverlay').css('display', 'block')

        populateSelectOptions('Department',"removeDepartmentDepartment")
        
    } else {
    
        $('#removeDepartmentOverlay').css('display', 'none')
    
    }

}
```

```
<div class="modal" id="removeDepartmentOverlay">

            <div class="addDepLoc">

                <div class="row profileRow">

                    <h3 style="display: inline">Department:</h3>
                    <select id="removeDepartmentDepartment" style="display: inline; float: right;"></select>
                
                </div>
                
                <br>
                <br>

                <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pt-3" id="removeDepLocBtn">
                
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">

                        <button class="button buttonClose" style="display: inline; float: left;" onclick="toggleRemoveDepartment()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-xs" style="font-size: 0.9em;"></i></button> 

                    </div>

                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">

                        <div class="btn btn-xs btn-primary5" id="confirmButton" style="display: inline; float: right;" onclick="toggleConfirmDep('Remove', 'removeDepartment()')"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-xs" aria-hidden="true" view="" type="button" style="font-size: 1em;" data-toggle="modal"></i></div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: You definitely want to put you database connection in a secure 700 folder and `require_once 'connection.php';` or `require 'connection.php';` it. You shouldn't have to get the departments just to remove one or more. The code that gets your departments should be a in a separate method.  Write a condition in MySQL. Just comments.

Comment: a) `departmentName` is a string, you cannot seal it. b) what does this have to do with the serverside database?!